# Markdown console application?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I hope you all will forgive me for asking this here, but since this site probably attracts many that are MarkDown-friendly I thought it would be a good place to start.

I have been thinking (which is almost always a dangerous thing, believe me), and I have a huge repository (in the non-version control sense of the word) of documents containing specifications for code I've written in the past.

The problem is that I never seem to settle on anything that stands the test of time. I have a bunch of Word files, a bunch of OpenOffice writer files, a huge bunch of text files, etc.

The specification really needs just two things:

- It needs to be versionable, I need to be able to check the file into source control, do meaningful diffs between versions, etc.
- It needs to output something slightly better formatted than just pure text

So, I thought about using MarkDown. I know that HTML strictly follows the above two rules, but let me add a third that makes HTML go away:

- It needs to be readable and easily editable in its source form as well, diffs needs to be understandable in the source form

In any case, is there a MarkDown implementation written as a console application, so that I could run my markdown text file through it to produce a html page, useful for printing, or serving on the web or whatnot?

Baring that, is there a MarkDown implementation for C# that would be easy to use for this that I could write my own tool around?

I know there are various perl and whatnot implementations but I'd rather have a pure .exe (even if it is a .NET exe) than a perl installation.

Comment: Before you settle on Markdown, consider reStructuredText too: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp) is Stack Overflow's server side implementation of Markdown.

Comment: I knew there was something I was missing.